# Text, followed by dashed line, then more text (centered), followed by dashed lines

Tags: html, css

Trying to achieve something similar to this:

> Some text ----------- Centered Button -----------

This is what I have so far, but it does not end up looking like above.

.html

```
<div class="dashed">
   <span>Some Text</span>
   <button>Centered button</button>
<div>
```

css

```
.dashed {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #000;
  text-align: center;
  height: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.dashed span {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.dashed button {
  text-align: center;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

Any pointers on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add dashes using `:after` & `:before` pseudo classes.

```css
.dashed {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dashed span {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.dashed button {
  text-align: center;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
    
    .dashed:before,
    .dashed:after {
      content: "-------------";
    }
```

```html
<div>
   <span>Some Text</span>
   <div class="dashed"><button>Centered button</button></div>
<div>
```

Comment: Thanks, the issue with this is that we've hardcoded the number of dashes. I'd like the dashes to occupy both the left and right of the button to take up the whole line (similar to jsfiddle.net/5wd7jtmc but with the first line of text on the same line as the rest)